# Error "Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior" when adding new libraries

Tags: android, gradle, ucrop

I am getting this error when I am trying to add new libraries to my project and then run my app:

> Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior

Following are the libraries I am trying to add

1. `implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'`
2. `implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2'`

Here is my app level gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.techxee.adarsh.chatbeta"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    //For firebase UI
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    //For bottom navigation bar
    implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    //FOR TAB LAYOUT
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
    //sweet alert dialog
    //implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1'
    //Shine button
    implementation 'com.sackcentury:shinebutton:0.2.0'
    //side menu
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:Side-Menu.Android:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar'
    //Image cropper library for the profile image, commented one generates error in compilation
    //implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is the Log:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\207.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\208.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\210.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\211.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\216.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\239.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\240.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\241.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\434.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\435.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\436.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\437.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\438.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\439.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\440.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\441.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\442.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\443.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\444.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\445.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\446.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\447.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\449.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\451.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\466.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\467.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\468.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\469.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\470.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\471.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\472.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\473.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\474.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\475.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\476.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\477.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\546.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\551.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\553.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\560.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\561.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\562.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\563.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\564.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\565.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\566.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\567.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\568.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\569.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\570.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\571.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\572.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\573.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\574.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\575.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\576.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\577.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\578.jar
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor638.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\207.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\208.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\210.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\211.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\216.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\239.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\240.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\241.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\434.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\435.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\436.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\437.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\438.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\439.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\440.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\441.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\442.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\443.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\444.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\445.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\446.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\447.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\449.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\451.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\466.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\467.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\468.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\469.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\470.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\471.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\472.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\473.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\474.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\475.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\476.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\477.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\546.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\551.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\553.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\560.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\561.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\562.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\563.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\564.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\565.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\566.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\567.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\568.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\569.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\570.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\571.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\572.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\573.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\574.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\575.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\576.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\577.jar, H:\Android u Projects\chatBeta\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\578.jar
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:124)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:109)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.transform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:123)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:76)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:67)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:107)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:77)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:58)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:67)
    ... 55 more
```

Answer (score 7):

This is because the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
```

is using support library version `27.1.1` (which can you see from its [project build.gradle](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/master/build.gradle) and [module build.gradle](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/master/cropper/build.gradle)) but you have mixed support libraries dependencies version 26 and 27.

So, you need to use a matching support library which is version 27.1.1. Change your build.gradle to something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27 // use version 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.techxee.adarsh.chatbeta"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27 // targeting api version 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

    // your other library
    // ...

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Hey, I made all of these changes but now it is throwing me the error "Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver"

Comment: I upgraded my firebase ui and firebase dependencies and that solved the problem. Thanks for you help

Comment: Congrats on fixing your problem ;)

Answer (score 3):

for my instance i had upgraded from

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0
```

to

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
```

i had to change back to old version and it worked.

Dont just mess up with gradle when things are oky. It maybe a pin it the ass.

Answer (score 3):

Just change `support:design:26.1.0` to:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updating support:design:26.1.0 to:
'com.android.support:design:27.1.1' worked for me.**
Higher than 27.1.1 will do just fine.
*If still not working try upgrading dependency 28*

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest for all of the  supportLibrary for example version 27.1.1 to solve the problem. worked for me. (many bug fixes included